# Как получить max гол?

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, position, number, goals):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.number = number
        self.goals = goals

    def toString(self):
        return 'Name: {}\nPosition: {}\nNumber: {}\nGoals: {}\n'.format(self.name, self.position, self.number, self.goals)

    def get_goals(self):
        return self.goals

p1 = Player('Salah', 'ATC', 11, 152)
p2 = Player('Ronaldinho', 'FRW', 10, 256)
p3 = Player('Pele', 'ATC', 7, 10)

lisp = [p1, p2, p3]

for p in sorted(lisp, key=lambda x: x.goals, reverse=True):
    print(p.toString())

for j in lisp:
    print(max(j.get_goals()))
```

> File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled1/example1.py", line 24,
>   in 
>       print(max(j.get_goals())) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: не мешало бы в теле вопроса как-то поподробнее писать что вы хотите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
for j in lisp:
    print(max(j.get_goals()))
```

на

```
print(max(lisp, key=lambda x: x.goals).toString())
```

max - это функция, которую нужно применить к последовательности элементов. Её нельзя применить для одного элемента, если он не является последовательностью.

Вы же перебираете в цикле отдельные элементы, и для каждого элемента по отдельности дёргаете max, поэтому и ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с ответом выше. От себя добавлю, что вместо реализации своего метода toString() в классе Player лучше было бы просто реализовать __str__(self), и тогда бы можно было писать не

```
print(max(lisp, key=lambda x: x.goals).toString())
```

а только

```
print(max(lisp, key=lambda x: x.goals))
```